# db.system.profile command execution in shell

Tags: mongodb

I was  trying out the mongo db performance in production environment

For this i ran this below command found from the net

```
db.system.profile.aggregate({ $group : { _id :"$op", 
count:{$sum:1}, 
"max response time":{$max:"$millis"}, 
"avg response time":{$avg:"$millis"} 
}});
```

For which the result was

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "getmore",
            "count" : 1,
            "max response time" : 0,
            "avg response time" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : "command",
            "count" : 43,
            "max response time" : 30,
            "avg response time" : 0.6976744186046512
        },
        {
            "_id" : "query",
            "count" : 150,
            "max response time" : 52,
            "avg response time" : 0.7
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

From where this id's getmore, command, query appeared? What does max response time indicate for each id?

Answer (score 1):

This is an aggregation of all the profiled DB accesses based on the "op" field of the profile entries.  From the [Mongo Profile Field Description doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/)

```
op -- The type of operation. The possible values are:

insert
query
update
remove
getmore
command
```

The max response time is therefore the maximum response time for any Db operation of the given type.  For example the maximum response time for any of the 150 query operations was 52 milliseconds.